# How can I change a data parameter in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, parameters, boolean

I have a problem changing a data parameter in my component file:

```
this.commandList.ListesCommandesATransmettre.forEach(data => {
    this.catalogs.forEach(catalog => {
        if (catalog.Libelle === data.Catalogue) {
            if (catalog.selected === false) {
                console.log(data.isSelected)
                data.isSelected = false;
                console.log(data.isSelected)
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

This code displays:

> true
>   false

But the value of `isSelected` in `console.log(data)` is still `true`. So, why is the result `false`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the variable this.commandList and this.catalogs? please

Comment: I think it's because you have 2 foreach loops. So the console is displaying the latest `data` that it had. try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`. or doing a `console.log(this.commandList);` outside of your loops

Comment: rhavelka : I have isSelected = false inside         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: I reproduce something similar on Stackblitz and it works
https://angular-yfgsay.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it's a loop problem with the callback

```
for (let data of this.commandList.ListesCommandesATransmettre) {
  for (let catalog of this.catalogs) {
    if (catalog.Libelle === data.Catalogue) {
      if (catalog.selected === false) {
        console.log(data.isSelected)
        data.isSelected = false;
        console.log(data.isSelected)
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand logic of your code. What happen if `this.catalogs` has many catalogs that meet the condition? `isSelected` will be setted many times in false.

Maybe this works (if I understand your logic):

```
this.commandList.ListesCommandesATransmettre = this.commandList.ListesCommandesATransmettre.map(data => {
    const mutateData = Object.assign({}, data);

    // If condition math, then isSelected set in false. Else, isSelected keep the his value
    mutateData.isSelected = 
        this.catalogs.some(catalog => catalog.Libelle === data.Catalogue && !catalog.selected) ? false : mutateData.isSelected;

    return mutateData;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to test if it is updating correctly. the loop will tell which are true/false and you can see if that is the case in the updated data.

```
this.commandList.ListesCommandesATransmettre.forEach((data, index) => {
    this.catalogs.forEach(catalog => {
        if (catalog.Libelle === data.Catalogue) {
            if (catalog.selected === false) {
                data.isSelected = false;
            }
            console.log(index + 'is selected: ' + data.isSelected)
        }
    })
});
console.log(this.commandlist);
```

Something I have noticed is that web browsers will only keep the the 'most current' reference of an object in memory. So after a loop has ended, the 'most current' reference is the last one to fire. So you may be looking at your last object and not the one you are trying to test. If someone else knows more, or has a reference to what is actually happening, please edit this post.